Shopware 6 extending administration services not working (6.5.7.8)
I have to extend an administration service, for example the cmsService. I have added the following code in the main.js - but it's not working:
Shopware.Application.$container.resetProviders(['cmsService']);
Shopware.Application.addServiceProviderDecorator('cmsService',  (cmsService) => {
    console.log("addServiceProviderDecorator::cmsService => not working");
    return cmsService;
});

The same with the example from the documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v6.5/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/extending-services.html
Shopware.Application.$container.resetProviders(['acl']);
Shopware.Application.addServiceProviderDecorator('acl', (aclService) => {
    aclService.foo = 'bar';
    console.log(aclService);
    return aclService;
});

